# SQL Server : Gap / Island, datetime, contiguous block 365 day block

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that looks like this:-

**tblMeterReadings**

> id meter         period_start              period_end            amount
>       1    1        2014-01-01 00:00   2014-01-01 00:29:59     100.3
>       2    1        2014-01-01 00:30   2014-01-01 00:59:59      50.5
>       3    1        2014-01-01 01:00   2014-01-01 01:29:59      70.7
>       4    1        2014-01-01 01:30   2014-01-01 01:59:59      900.1
>       5    1        2014-01-01 02:00   2014-01-01 02:29:59      400.0
>       6    1        2014-01-01 02:30   2014-01-01 02:59:59      200.3
>       7    1        2014-01-01 03:00   2014-01-01 03:29:59      100.8
>       8    1        2014-01-01 03:30   2014-01-01 03:59:59      140.3

This is a tiny "contiguous block" from `'2014-01-01 00:00' to '2014-01-01 3:59:59'`.

In the real table there are "contiguous blocks" of years in length.

I need to find the the period_start and period_end of the most recent **CONTINUOUS 365 COMPLETE DAYs** (fileterd by meter column).

When I say **COMPLETE DAYs** I mean a day that has entries spanning `00:00 to 23:59`.
When I say **CONTINUOUS** I mean there must be no days missing.

I would like to select all the rows that make up this block of **CONTINUOUS COMPLETE DAYs**.

I also need an output like:

> block_start                  block_end              total_amount_for_block
>       2013-02-26 00:00    2014-02-26 23:59:59              1034234.5

This is beyond me, so if someone can solve... I will be very impressed.

Comment: Try searching for `itzik ben-gan gaps islands`

Comment: How do the period start? Is this always half an hour starting at full hour? If no can it start on one day and end on another?

Comment: COMPLETE DAY - record for every 30 minutes in a day?

Comment: @JakubKania the gaps MAY not be half an hour satring on the full hour, but they will always be between 00:00 and 23:59:59, they will not span to another day.

Comment: @rudym the chunks that make up a COMPLETE DAY may not be 30 mins, for the avoidance of doubt, it could be one read starting at 00:00 ending at 23:59:59 or three reads one starting at 00:00:00 to 01:19:59, then another 01:20:00 to 3:44:59, then a final one 3:45:00 to 23:59:59.

Comment: The maximum granularity is one second.

Comment: Thank you @podiluska, I'll have a read.  I'm still hoping an expert can get me moving though.

Comment: INCIDENTALLY.  Would I be better to save the timespans at 00:00:00 to 00:30:00, then 00:30:00 to 01:00:00 rather than 00:00:00 to 00:29:59 then 00:30:00 to 00:59:59?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your granularity is 1 second, you need to expand your periods into all the date/times between the start and end at 1 second intervals. To do this you need to cross join with a numbers table (The numbers table is generated on the fly by ranking object ids from an arbitrary system view, I have limited it to TOP 86400 since this is the number of seconds in a day, and you have stated your time periods never span more than one day):

```
WITH Numbers AS
(   SELECT  TOP (86400) 
            Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1
    FROM    sys.all_objects a
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
    ORDER BY a.object_id
)
SELECT  r.ID, r.meter, dt.[DateTime]
FROM    tblMeterReadings r
        CROSS JOIN Numbers n
        OUTER APPLY 
        (   SELECT [DateTime] = DATEADD(SECOND, n.Number, r.period_start)
        ) dt
WHERE   dt.[DateTime] <= r.Period_End;
```

You then have your continuous range in which to perform the normal gaps and islands grouping:

```
WITH Numbers AS
(   SELECT  TOP (86400) 
            Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1
    FROM    sys.all_objects a
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
    ORDER BY a.object_id
), Grouped AS
(   SELECT  r.meter, 
            Amount = CASE WHEN Number = 1 THEN r.Amount ELSE 0 END,
            dt.[DateTime],
            GroupingSet = DATEADD(SECOND, 
                                    -DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY r.Meter 
                                                        ORDER BY dt.[DateTime]), 
                                    dt.[DateTime])
    FROM    tblMeterReadings r
            CROSS JOIN Numbers n
            OUTER APPLY 
            (   SELECT [DateTime] = DATEADD(SECOND, n.Number, r.period_start)
            ) dt
    WHERE   dt.[DateTime] <= r.Period_End
)
SELECT  meter, 
        PeriodStart = MIN([DateTime]), 
        PeriodEnd = MAX([DateTime]), 
        Amount = SUM(Amount)
FROM    Grouped
GROUP BY meter, GroupingSet
HAVING DATEADD(YEAR, 1, MIN([DateTime])) < MAX([DateTime]);
```

*N.B. Since the join to `Number` causes amounts to be duplicated, it is necessary to set all duplicates to 0 using* `CASE WHEN Number = 1 THEN r.Amount ELSE 0 END`, *i.e only include the amount for the first row for each ID*

Removing the Having clause for your sample data will give:

```
meter | PeriodStart         | PeriodEnd           | Amount
------+---------------------+---------------------+----------
1     | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | 2014-01-01 03:59:59 |  1963
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb101/3)**

Comment: That looks like it does the job... Thank you. What is the significance of 86400?  Are you able to add some comments to help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Also... if you were designing this, would you do the time spans as 00:00:00 -> 00:30:00, 00:30:00 to 01:00:00 or, how I have?

Comment: 86400 is just the number of seconds in one day, this is the maximum amount of numbers required if your periods never span more than one day. Yes I would recommend having the end datetime exclusive of the period, so `00:00:00 -> 00:30:00, 00:30:00 -> 01:00:00`. For this particular query it does not make much difference, but for others it might. My reasoning is pretty much covered in this artice: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Thank you.  I will change the spans, to reflect your comments.

Comment: If I do that, would you change your query, or should I go with that?

Comment: You would just need to change `WHERE dt.[DateTime] <= r.Period_End` to `WHERE dt.[DateTime] < r.Period_End`. This is the only change required.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this would have taken me a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Select MIN(period_start) as "block start"
     , MAX(period_end) as "block end"
     , SUM(amount) as "total amount"
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY    datepart(year, period_start)
        ,   datepart(month, period_start)
        ,   datepart(day, period_start)
        ,   datepart(year, period_end)
        ,   datepart(month, period_end)
        ,   datepart(day, period_end)
Having      datepart(year, period_start) = datepart(year, period_end)
        AND datepart(month, period_start) = datepart(month, period_end)
        AND datepart(day, period_start) = datepart(day, period_end)
        AND datepart(hour,  MIN(period_start)) = 0 
        AND datepart(minute,MIN(period_start)) = 0
        AND datepart(hour,  MAX(period_end)) = 23
        AND datepart(minute,MIN(period_end)) = 59
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem... it's more complex than that.